# removing words from string using regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping  the website using Scrapy which has product list on it. What I want to do is to remove unwanted words from the product titles string with regex. There are 2 different repeating words I want to remove: **Pen** and **Graphite Pencil** and scrape only the brand names.

Any suggestions?

```
<a name=“this-link”> href=“some url here”>Pen Bic Crystal</a>

some divs and other DOM structure

<a name=“this-link”> href=“some url here”>Graphite Pencil Kohinoor Carpenter</a>

some divs and other DOM structure

<a name=“this-link”> href=“some url here”>Pen Parker Jotter</a>

some divs and other DOM structure

<a name=“this-link”> href=“some url here”>Pen Bic Other Model</a>

some divs and other DOM structure

<a name=“this-link”> href=“some url here”>Graphite Pencil Palomino Blackwing Pearl</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy selectors have built-in [support for regular expressions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions).

Call `re()` after getting link texts:

```
sel.xpath('//a/text()').re(r'(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)\s(.*)')
```

where:

- `sel` is your [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) instance
- `(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)` is a [non-capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)
- `(.*)` is a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping)

UPD:

If you want to get only the following word after `Pen` or `Graphite Pencil`, use this regular expression: `r'(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)\s(\w+)`, where only set of alphanumeric (and `_`) characters are captured after `Pen` or `Graphite Pencil` and a space.

Demo using [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> sel.xpath('//a/text()').re(r'(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)\s(\w+)')
[u'Bic', u'Kohinoor', u'Parker', u'Bic', u'Palomino']
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alecxe .
Is there chance to add additional regex to your answer, like removing these 2 and filtering only the following word? Like to have only Parker, or Bic?

Comment: @ikechi yup, sure, let me make a demo then.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Was going through regex syntax now and if for example I want to scrape model names, like Kohinoor Carpenter or Crystal, can this work? 

`sel.xpath('//a/text()').re(r'(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)\s('\s+(.*)$')`

Sorry, I'm not at my work PC right now to test it, can apply this after 2-3 hours.

Comment: @ikechi ok, if a model name is everything after `Pen` or `Graphite Pencil`, then you should be good with `(?:Pen|Graphite Pencil)\s(.*)`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: remove pen and graphite pencil and skip brand. In first scenario regex grabs only brand. In other scenario regex grabs everything after brand name, i.e only model name. Brands are always one word after pen or graphite pencil.